# split string and store it into HashMap java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I want to split below string and store it into HashMap.

```
String responseString = "name~peter-add~mumbai-md~v-refNo~";
```

first I split the string using delimeter hyphen (-) and storing it into ArrayList as below:

```
 public static List<String> getTokenizeString(String delimitedString, char separator) {
    final Splitter splitter = Splitter.on(separator).trimResults();
    final Iterable<String> tokens = splitter.split(delimitedString);
    final List<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String token: tokens){
        tokenList.add(token);
    }
    return tokenList;
}
List<String> list = MyClass.getTokenizeString(responseString, "-");
```

and then using the below code to convert it to HashMap using stream.

```
HashMap<String, String> = list.stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.toMap(k ->k.split("~")[0], v -> v.split("~")[1]));
```

The stream collector doesnt work as there is no value against refNo.

It works correctly if I have even number of elements in ArrayList.

Is there any way to handle this? Also suggest how I can use stream to do these two tasks (I dont want to use getTokenizeString() method) using stream java 8.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unless `Splitter` is doing any magic, the `getTokenizeString` method is obsolete here. You can perform the entire processing as a single operation:

```
Map<String,String> map = Pattern.compile("\\s*-\\s*")
    .splitAsStream(responseString.trim())
    .map(s -> s.split("~", 2))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a.length>1? a[1]: ""));
```

By using the regular expression `\s*-\s*` as separator, you are considering white-space as part of the separator, hence implicitly trimming the entries. There’s only one initial `trim` operation before processing the entries, to ensure that there is no white-space before the first or after the last entry.

Then, simply split the entries in a `map` step before collecting into a `Map`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and working answer. Working like charm.

Comment: Is using `split()` two time , once for `-` and another for `~` ok??

Comment: @VishwaRatna since these are two independent operations, with different semantics, there is nothing wrong with performing them independently. What you should avoid, is to perform redundant operations, like the `split("~")` which was performed two times on the same input in the original code.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you don't have to split the same `String` twice.
Second of all, check the length of the array to determine if a value is present for a given key.

```
HashMap<String, String> map= 
    list.stream()
        .map(s -> s.split("~"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a.length > 1 ? a[1] : ""));
```

This is assuming you want to put the key with a `null` value if a key has no corresponding value.

Or you can skip the `list` variable :

```
HashMap<String, String> map1 = 
    MyClass.getTokenizeString(responseString, "-")
        .stream()
        .map(s -> s.split("~"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a.length > 1 ? a[1] : ""));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. it seems that it will only split on ~ and not hyphen. and also How can I get rid of first getTokenizeString() method.

Comment: I tried your code.It throws NullPointerException. it only works for even sized list.

Comment: @SangamBelose This code assumes you keep `List<String> list = MyClass.getTokenizeString(responseString, "-");`

Comment: even If I keep MyClass.getTokenizeString(responseString, "-"); it throws the null pointer. it fails on the  last array value.

Answer (score 1):

```
private final String dataSheet = "103343262,6478342944, 103426540,84528784843, 103278808,263716791426, 103426733,27736529279, 
103426000,27718159078, 103218982,19855201547, 103427376,27717278645, 
103243034,81667273413";

    final int chunk = 2;
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    Map<String, String> pairs = Arrays.stream(dataSheet.split(","))
            .map(String::trim)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> counter.getAndIncrement() / chunk))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .collect(toMap(k -> k.get(0), v -> v.get(1)));
```

> result:

```
pairs =
 "103218982" -> "19855201547"
 "103278808" -> "263716791426"
 "103243034" -> "81667273413"
 "103426733" -> "27736529279"
 "103426540" -> "84528784843"
 "103427376" -> "27717278645"
 "103426000" -> "27718159078"
 "103343262" -> "6478342944"
```

> We need to group each 2 elements into key, value pairs, so will partion the list into chunks of 2, (counter.getAndIncrement() / 2) will result same number each 2 hits ex:

```
IntStream.range(0,6).forEach((i)->System.out.println(counter.getAndIncrement()/2));
prints:
0
0
1
1
2
2
```

> You may use the same idea to partition list into chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Another short way to do :

```
String responseString = "name~peter-add~mumbai-md~v-refNo~";
Map<String, String> collect = Arrays.stream(responseString.split("-"))
                              .map(s -> s.split("~", 2))
                              .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a.length > 1 ? a[1] : ""));
                              System.out.println(collect);
```

First you split the String on basis of `-` , then you map like `map(s -> s.split("~", 2))`it to create `Stream<String[]>` like `[name, peter][add, mumbai][md, v][refNo, ]` and at last you collect it to `toMap` as `a[0]` goes to key  and `a[1]` goes to value.